# Are Gods present in Materialistic form?

Tags: gods, creation

Are the Gods created after the Supreme consciousness created the Universe present in Materialistic forms? Ex. Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, Saraswati, Lakshmi, Parvati, Indra, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as we say God is omnipresent. Refer **[CC Ādi 2.49](https://www.vedabase.com/en/cc/adi/2/49)**

> kāraṇābdhi-garbhodaka-kṣīrodaka-śāyī māyā-dvāre sṛṣṭi kare, tāte saba
>   māyī
>
> “The Kāraṇodakaśāyī, Garbhodakaśāyī and Kṣīrodakaśāyī **forms of
>   Nārāyaṇa** all create in cooperation with the material energy. In this
>   way They are attached to māyā.

Also [refer](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gita/agsgita.htm) the following:

> The mind, intellect, ego, ether, air, fire, water, and earth are the
>   eight fold division of **My material energy**. (See also 13.05) (7.04)
>
> The **material Nature** or matter is **My lower Nature**. My other higher
>   Nature is the Spirit by which this entire universe is sustained, O
>   Arjuna. (7.05)
>
> Know that **three modes of material Nature** goodness, passion, and
>   ignorance also emanate from Me. I am not dependent on, or affected by,
>   the modes of material Nature; but the modes of material Nature are
>   dependent on Me. (See also 9.04 and 9.05) (7.12)
>
> All manifestations come out of the **primary material Nature** during the
>   creative cycle, and they merge into the primary material Nature during
>   the destructive cycle.